# ~1300ms latency touching file on nfs mount

Tags: centos, centos7, nfs, latency, nfs4

I have an NFS mount where the server is on the same subnet as the client. 
When I `time touch testempty` from the client, I get:

```
touch testempty  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.325 total
```

The time follows an bizarre pattern - Most of the time it's just over one second, but approximately once per minute it spikes to around 1.3. See this graph, compiled from time it takes to touch a nonexistent file, once every ten seconds:

[image: graph of latency]

When I `rm testempty` then `time touch testempty` from the server, I get:

```
touch testempty  0.00s user 0.00s system 29% cpu 0.005 total
```

So disk isn't the problem. Ping shows sub-200us latency, so network isn't the problem either. I've found that **this still happens when the server mounts its own share.**

Here is my `/etc/exports`:

```
/data           192.168.0.0/16(rw,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,insecure,sec=sys,fsid=0)
/data/dba_work  192.168.0.0/16(rw,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,insecure,sec=sys,fsid=1)
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Server is running CentOS 7. Have tried multiple different Linux clients, including the server itself.

Comment: you can check with wireshark which request are slow. 1.3 sec is tooooo much.

Comment: It sounds like server side processing time and not the network. No network should have 1s or more RTT - heck, not even the Internet across the globe is that bad.

Comment: @PedroPerez As my post said, I am fully aware of that.

Comment: Not sure how I´ve missed that, apologies!